# Getting the object out of the http response received

Tags: mule

1st ESB App: HTTP Inbound Endpoint(request-response) -> javaComponent1 -> http outbound endpoint(request-response) -> JavaComponent2.
2nd ESB app: HTTP Inbound Endpoint(request-response) -> javacomponent3

In my case HTTP Inbound Endpoint(request-response) of 2nd ESB app sends the response back to the http outbound endpoint(request-response) of 1st ESB App.

My problem and query: HTTP Inbound Endpoint(request-response) of 2nd ESB app should send a java object as payload of the request that is being sent back to the http outbound endpoint(request-response) of 1st ESB App. The JavaComponent2 should be able to read the object received by the http outbound endpoint(request-response) of 1st ESB App and process it further.

How should I send my Java object from the http endpoint of the second app to the http outbound endpoint of the first app? I cannot use serialization here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object to bytearray transformer before sending the object from the 2nd Mule app . Then you use bytearray to Object transformer after the http outbound endpoint in the 1st mule app, while you are receiving the response from the 2nd mule app

First App

```
<flow name="test_serializableFlow1" doc:name="test_serializableFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<logger message="Before transformer  #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<byte-array-to-object-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to Object"/>
<logger message="After transformer   #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Second app

```
<flow name="ssFlow1" doc:name="ssFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<component class="Test" doc:name="Java"/>
<object-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="Object to Byte Array"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: Naveen this will not work for the object you are transferring between two different esb apps. You will get serialization exception in doing so.

Comment: I thinks you need to serialize the object before sending